# Memory-wise, is it better to save a formula as a string or an expression (symbol), in Julia

Tags: math, memory, julia, expression, symbols

I deal with lots of mathematical expressions in a certain Julia script and would like to know if storing such a formula as a String is ok, or whether using the Symbol data type is better. Thinking about scalability and keeping memory requirements to a minimum. Thanks!

**Update**: the application involves a machine learning model. Ideally, it should be applicable to big data too, hence the need for scalability.

Comment: Almost certainly an expression object

Comment: Expressions and symbols are different things. But the question is underspecified, IMHO. What is the use case? What kinds of expressions do you have, and what would you do with them?

Comment: How many is "lots"? How often are those expressions evaluated or manipulated?

Comment: Without more info I have two general "rules: (1) Using symbols is almost surely more efficient than storing strings, (2) difficile that point 1 is the bottleneck of a program. I do have however a certainty: using symbols in an API would complicate things for nebbies (with mixing the two being the worst)

Comment: @Zack I propose that you elaborate more on your exact use case. Perhaps also make a sample formula. This would surely get you a more useful answer. One good way to store expression is a Julia source code (that can be statically compiled if fast loading is needed)

Answer (score 2):

In a string, each character is stored based on its number of `codeunit`s, eg. 1 for ascii. The same is true for the characters of a Symbol. So that is a wash; do what fits your use best, probably Symbols since you are manipulating expressions.

An expression like `:(x + y)` is stored as a list of Any, with space allocated according to the `sizeof` each item in the expression.

In an expression like `:(7 + 4 * 9)` versus a string like `"7 +       4 *      9"`  there are two conflicting issues.  First, 7 is stored as 1 byte in the string, but 8 bytes in the expression since there are 64-bit Ints in play. On the other hand, whitespace takes up 1 byte each space in the string, but does not use memory in the expression. And a number like 123.123456789 takes up 14 bytes in the string and 8 in the expression (64 bit floats).

I think that, again, this is close to being even, and depends on the specific strings you are parsing. You could, as you work with the program, store both, compare memory usage of the resulting arrays, and drop one type of storage if you feel you should.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to compare memory usage of the various data types (if there is one, I am not aware of it). I see your point though. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: you could use `sizeof` to check the size of a particular object.